# setPropertyActionListener not working after p:datatable filtering

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

**What it does**

I have a webapp that uses PrimeFaces 3.1.1. The aim of the app is to provide a more user friendly way of traversing the XML aggregator we have. It was originally written in SCALA, but now I've implemented it in Java.

**What the issue is**

There is an option, when a user selects a bunch of XML files, to parse those files and display their value in a user friendly way. When I don't filter anything, this works perfectly, however as soon as I filter my datatable, it starts behaving in a really bizarre way. It get's hung on files and doesn't update to the currently selected XML file.

For example, here, you can see I have selected the `feed details` for a file, but I'm getting feed details for a previously selected file.

[image: example of error]

Here is the code for an example button:

```
 <p:commandButton oncomplete="mungeBetResultDialog.show()"
                             update=":mungeBetResultForm" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search"
                             title="view changes" rendered="#{searchBean.isFootballMungeResult(feed.xml)}"
                             style="height:20px;">

        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{feed}" target="#{searchBean.selectedFeed}"/>
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{searchBean.showFeedDetails}"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

The example button exists in every row of the `DataTable`. The DataTable has no backing bean.

**What I've managed to work out**

So I've noticed that it's specifically one of the action listeners that aren't firing. This one:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{feed}" target="#{searchBean.selectedFeed}"/>
```

I added a log to the code this calls, and after filtering it works for some and not for others, whereas before it worked perfectly.

***NOTE***: This bug *ONLY* occurs if I try to view the details of a feed after I have filtered it. This tells me there is some sort of issue on the front end, rather than an issue with the code on the back end.

**My question**

Is there some sort of well known bug in PrimeFaces that disables the `setPropertyActionListener` tag from firing at the appropriate time? I've seen bugs stopping `commandLinks`, but the fixes that have been suggested there don't seem to work for me.

Comment: Are you sure that only one of the two action listeners are called? If yes, that's strange, if no - add `<h:messages>` to see if there are any errors stopping invoke application phase to be passed through.

Comment: Well the second one loads the `feed details` dialogue, and that always appears. I'll look into adding `<h:messages>` now though and edit the result into my question.

Comment: You so confidently stated that one of the two action listeners is executed, while the other one fails, but that is really weird. It feels that `true` could have been set due to the previous ajax request.

Comment: Adding `h:messages` tag to my code didn't really make a difference at all; I didn't see any logs appear from it. And I know it's working because the dialog always appears, and it won't appear if `true` is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The bug](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3467) seems to be fixed for 3.4. Do you have any chance to upgrade to it?

> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>
> 1. Set up a datatable with a filter and a commandLink or any other ActionSource component as row content
> 2. Filter the datatable
> 3. Click on a link of the filtered rows of the datatable

[Cagatay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306753/cagatay-civici):

> So, I've tried the sample in comment 3, replicated the problem with 3.1 (bundled in sample), 3.2 and 3.3.
>
> But not with 3.4-SNAPSHOT, functionality worked as expected.
>
> Reason is probably the maintenance work of 3.4;
>
> http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4270
>
> So I can confirm there was a bug but seems to be fixed in 3.4, If you set the PF version to 3.4-SNAPSHOT in the sample of comment #3, it should work. Marking as fixed.

Comment: I upgraded to version 4, but that was just an absolute nightmare when I ran it. I had hoped to fix this with version 3.1.1. I'll update it, and check the results.

Comment: Go with 3.5. 4 probably has major changes.

Comment: I tried 3.5. Maven starting complaining that it couldn't find it. I'll give it another go. Still +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: You have to include the PF repo in your configuration. It is definitely [there](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/)

Comment: Yeah, I have definitely included it. We're running through a local nexus server first, before going to the central maven repository, so the chances are, that server is what's playing up. I'll stick at it and try to get 3.5 working.

Comment: So I couldn't get 3.5 working, so I moved onto 4.0. After a bit of tweaking, I've managed to get it working well. Your suggestion was what got me in the right direction so I'll make it as correct. Thankyou!

Comment: Glad to hear that! By the way, take care with your PF-JSF versions. PF 4 is tied to JSF 2.2.x, as PF 3.x are to 2.x, 2.1.x.